# Obtener variable de blade en Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, blade

Tengo una URL de este estilo
https://site1.local/cars/upload-images?id=22

Es un proceso que hago en diversos pasos, y en este punto quiero cojer de la URL el dia, para usarlo en javascript.

Tengo un fichero blade y dentro tengo código jquery para manipular ciertos datos.

He conseguido cojer el valor desde blade con esta sentencia

```
 {{ Request::get('id')  }}
```

Con esto tengo el valor de "ID" que lo printa por pantalla, pero este valor me gustaría ponerlo aquí dentro

```
 var categoryId = "OBTENER EL ID";

 var editUrl = '{{ route("front.cars.uploadImages", ':categoryId') }}';
 editUrl = editUrl.replace(':categoryId', categoryId);
```

Gracias,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no vas a editar el id, puedes pasarlo directamente

```
var editUrl = '{{ route("front.cars.uploadImages", Request::get("id")) }}';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias...me estava liando con los {! y {{